# Show Pagination in Category Listing Page

Tags: magento

I have created a custom phtml file for categories in which i am listing child categories of parent category.

I want to show pagination tool bar in that category listing is there anyway to do that?

Answer (score 0):

you can set collection in _preparelayout function as below code in your block file

protected function _prepareLayout()
    {

```
    parent::_prepareLayout();
    $toolbar = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager');
    if ($toolbar) {

       $toolbar->setAvailableLimit(array(10=>10,20=>20,'all'=>'All'));
        $toolbar->setCollection($this->getCollection());
        $this->setChild('toolbar', $toolbar);

    }
    return $this;
}

public function getToolbarHtml()
{
    return $this->getChildHtml('toolbar');
}
```

and call in your phtml file by

```
 $this->getToolbarHtml();
```